# reporting script. Want to report machines that are missing a certain file

Tags: powershell

Currently have this, but it only reports the machines with chrome and the version. Id like it to also report the machines that are offline, or more importantly missing the file.

Any tips

ta

```
$Computers = Get-Adcomputer -Filter * 
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
$PC = $computer.dnshostname
 $hostname = $PC.split('.')[0]
Write-Host "\\$PC\c`$\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
$exe = "\\$pc\c`$\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

if  ( Test-Path  $exe){
    $ver = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($exe).FileVersion
    Add-Content -path .\results.csv "$exe,$ver"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the host is accessible first, then check if the file is present only if the host is actually online. Create custom objects for each case and use a pipeline for exporting them to a CSV.

```
$Computers | ForEach-Object {
    $PC  = $_.dnshostname
    $exe = "\\$PC\C`$\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

    if (Test-Connection $PC -Count 3 -Quiet) {
        if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $exe){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Hostname    = $PC
                HostOnline  = $true
                FileExists  = $true
                FileVersion = [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($exe).FileVersion
            }
        } else {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Hostname    = $PC
                HostOnline  = $true
                FileExists  = $false
                FileVersion = $null
            }
        }
    } else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Hostname    = $PC
            HostOnline  = $false
            FileExists  = $null
            FileVersion = $null
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv '.\results.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the machine is reachable first and write a special entry into the file if it isn't. Similarly just write a different entry if the file can't be found:

```
$Computers = Get-Adcomputer -Filter * 
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $PC = $computer.dnshostname
    $hostname = $PC.split('.')[0]
    if (Test-Connection $hostname -Count 1) {
        Write-Host "\\$PC\c`$\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        $exe = "\\$pc\c`$\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        if  ( Test-Path  $exe){
            $ver = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($exe).FileVersion
            Add-Content -path .\results.csv "$exe,$ver"
        }
        else {
            Add-Content -path .\results.csv "File not found"
        }
    }
    else {
        Add-Content -path .\results.csv "Not reachable"
    }
}
```

Obviously you might want to change the text. Also wouldn't a column for the machinename make sense?